# ng-repeat continuously fired on hover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select2, angularjs-select2, ui-select

I'm using [UI-Select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) 0.8.4 and have a large data set. Then I'm using UI-Select to display property values in a dropdown beside the data set. I'm using that for filters. So when choosing from the dropdown, will filter the results.

Every time when I hover over some item in the dropdown, it always fires the ng-repeat filter.

This is lagging my application because I'm working with a large set in the ng-repeat.

Why is this?

GIF:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPBEz.gif

Plunker *(open console and see for yourself)*:
http://plnkr.co/edit/OxiutZ8t4IX1bOxiOTgo?p=preview

HTML:

```
<h3>Age list</h3>
  <p>Selected: {{age.selected}}</p>
  <ui-select ng-model="age.selected" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person">{{$select.selected}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="age in ageArray | filter: $select.search">
      <div ng-bind="age | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.theFilter = function(item) {
    console.log(item);
    return item;
  };

  $scope.ageArray = [];
  $scope.$watch('people', function(item) {
    for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
      $scope.ageArray.push(item[i].age);
    }
  });

  $scope.people = [
    { name: 'Adam',      email: 'adam@email.com',      age: 10 },
    { name: 'Amalie',    email: 'amalie@email.com',    age: 12 },
    { name: 'Wladimir',  email: 'wladimir@email.com',  age: 30 },
    { name: 'Samantha',  email: 'samantha@email.com',  age: 31 },
    { name: 'Estefanía', email: 'estefanía@email.com', age: 16 },
    { name: 'Natasha',   email: 'natasha@email.com',   age: 54 },
    { name: 'Nicole',    email: 'nicole@email.com',    age: 43 },
    { name: 'Adrian',    email: 'adrian@email.com',    age: 21 }
  ];
```

**Edit**: I even tried to filter the property values out of the "data set array" and using that in the dropdown, but it doesn't work.

**Edit 2:** If you think that the watch was triggering this, I removed the watch and this is still a problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/oD3Tt3vfjtOjADMnemW1?p=preview

**Edit 3:** Still haven't found a solution for this so I'm stuck with [chosen](https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen). I [created an issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/532) but haven't gotten any response. **Please upvote the issue if you want this fixed.**

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the filter is executing on every `$digest` (every ng-mouseenter, ng-click, etc). For a huge data set, this can obviously kill performance. (See this article http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2489-how-often-do-filters-execute-in-angularjs.htm)

Instead, try a `$watch` on the `age.selected` value, then applying a filter only when that value actually changes.

http://plnkr.co/edit/TIeKPAyrAQsGHwakqwEp?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<!-- filtered list "ageMatches" -->
<ul ng-show="age.selected">
  <li ng-repeat="person in ageMatches">{{person.name}} - {{person.age}}</li>
</ul>

<!-- default list of all "people" -->
<ul ng-hide="age.selected">
  <li ng-repeat="person in people">{{person.name}} - {{person.age}}</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
// add age to scope
$scope.age = {};

// add age match placeholder  
$scope.ageMatches = [];

// watch age.selected for changes, apply filter
$scope.$watch('age.selected', function(newVal, oldVal){
  if(newVal){
    $scope.ageMatches = $filter('filter')($scope.people, {age: newVal});
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but this filter I'm using is very complex and consists of many ng-models under $scope.filters.* - I think it's bloat to add a watch for each one, instead of having it in the ng-repeat. The question is however, is the ng-mouseenter necessary? Does it need to fire on hover, not just click? I personally think this is a flaw in the library.

Comment: Agreed, worst part is, I think the only purpose of the mouseenter is to apply an "active" class... too bad this ends up killing performance #cssplease

Comment: Might suggest removing the ng-mouseenter from the templating in the lib code.

Comment: What did you do finally?